# Finding and removing unnecessary redirects

Tags: url-rewriting, html

I have a bunch of redirects to sites like sharethis, media6, and some random character urls. Most of these are leading to a blank pixel or each other. I know a lot has to do with facebook and needed resources but how would I find out where these are being loaded from? So I can figure out what plugin is causing them and remove it if its not necessary.The last three are the main problem. But when I search the source I can not find them so it has to be some JS thats loading them. Also is there an easy way maybe at the server level (nginx) to access all these resources from my server through a cache or something? Short of changing the code to load them locally.

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700&subset=latin,latin-ext
https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1
http://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniqu2&locationId=1856968&lang=en_US&rating=true&nreviews=5&writereviewlink=true&popIdx=false&iswide=false&border=true
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
http://www.tripadvisor.com/WidgetEmbed-selfserveprop?border=true&popIdx=false&iswide=false&locationId=1856968&rating=true&uniqu2=&nreviews=5&lang=en_US&writereviewlink=true
http://static.addtoany.com/menu/page.js
http://wd-edge.sharethis.com/button/getAllAppDefault.esi?cb=stLight.allDefault&app=all&publisher=ur.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&domain=chflive.japayton.com
http://wd-edge.sharethis.com/button/checkOAuth.esi
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
http://www.google-analytics.com/r/__utm.gif?utmwv=5.6.4&utms=1&utmn=1610840262&utmhn=static.addtoany.com&utmcs=UTF-8&utmsr=1024x875&utmsc=24-bit&utmul=en-us&utmje=0&utmfl=11.2%20r202&utmdt=A2A&utmhid=1437638512&utmr=http%3A%2F%2Fchflive.japayton.com%2F&utmp=%2Fmenu%2Fsm12.html&utmht=1429399749431&utmac=UA-1244922-8&utmcc=__utma%3D66866668.767249130.1429399749.1429399749.1429399749.1%3B%2B__utmz%3D66866668.1429399749.1.1.utmcsr%3Dchflive.japayton.com%7Cutmccn%3D(referral)%7Cutmcmd%3Dreferral%7Cutmcct%3D%2F%3B&utmjid=1770988977&utmredir=1&utmu=qAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAE~
http://d.agkn.com/pixel/6644/?che=1429399749&sk=&lr=&py=&cp=&wb=
http://map.media6degrees.com/orbserv/hbpix?pixId=23460&pcv=46&cckz=true
http://p.nexac.com/e/sr/a-1548/s-3271/s-3271.xgi?rd=Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using the WP-Do-Not-Track plugin. I was able to black list all the addresses I did not want loaded. it works great and does not seem to change my page load speed.

A lot more than add to any was causing these.

Comment: This is the answer to my problem. Everything that had to be loaded was locally cached. All this stuff in my list was extra tracking code and it was all blocked by wp-do-not-track. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

While in the process of implementing a CSP and defining the allowed sources, I was shocked to find the total number of resources ShareThis calls. At the time of writing this, I counted a total of 39 domains and subdomains it uses.

Not a big surprise anymore why ShareThis was causing my slow page load times. From what I found, the majority of the calls are for ad and user habit tracking pixels. No wonder they're a free service, they're probably getting paid big bucks from companies to track what you’re doing. Though, I understand they need to connect to the various social network APIs to grab numbers, I don’t think they need to add tracking pixels for advertisements and user habits.

An example is adadvisor dot net and crwdcntrl dot net. Their domains used by Targus Info and Lotame which is an advertising company that is part of a network of sites, cookies, and other technologies used to track you, what you do and what you click on, as you go from site to site, surfing the Web. Over time, sites like adadvisor.net and crwdcntrl.net can help make an online profile of you usually including the sites you visit, your searches, purchases, and other behavior. Your profile can then be exchanged and sold between various companies as well as being sold to other advertisers and marketers.

**Alternatives to ShareThis**

After finding out everything ShareThis is doing, it was time to find some alternatives. Here’s some I’ve found that seem to be less resource intensive—though may still load ad and user habit tracking pixels, not nearly as many as ShareThis:

AddThis dot com
AddToAny dot com
Shareaholic dot com
Share42 dot com (very basic, no third-party scripts)

**WordPress Plugins**

If you prefer a more plug-and-play options, here’s some pretty good WordPress plugins and Drupal modules for social sharing.

1. Flare
   Flare is a simple yet eye-catching social sharing bar that gets you followed and lets your content get shared via posts, pages, and media types.
2. Social Count Plus
   Display the counting data of Twitter, Facebook, YouTube, Instagram, Steam Community, SoundCloud posts and comments.
3. Dig Dig
   Your all in one share buttons plugin. Add a floating bar with share buttons to your blog. Just like Mashable!
4. AddThis
   AddThis Share Buttons help drive traffic to your site by helping visitors share, bookmark and email your content to over 330 services.
5. Shareaholic
   Adds an attractive social bookmarking menu and related content widget to your posts, pages, index, or any combination of the three.

**Drupal Modules**

1. Social media
   The social media module helps integrate your website with social media sites such as Twitter, Facebook and Google+. It provides an centralized way of managing social media profile information and plug-in widgets such as follow and share buttons.
2. Easy Social
   Centered in a single place, you don’t need to worry in including external javascript libraries, and enabling several social modules.
3. AddToAny
   This module helpers your readers and subscribers share, email and bookmark your articles and pages using the popular services such as Facebook, Twitter, Pinterest and over 100 more.
4. AddThis
   This is the #1 bookmarking and sharing button on the net. Simple and easy to use button that’s used by 14 million websites worldwide and reaching 1.3 billion people worldwide per month.
5. Service links
   Service Links facilitates the adding of social networks links or javascript buttons within the content with a special focus on developers and themers interested to extend their number or customize their displaying. Built on Drupal for Drupal doesn’t include commercial advertising or spying hidden code and doesn’t require third part libraries.

[Link to original article](http://www.benmarshall.me/sharethis-slowing-down-site/)

Comment: I use addtoany now. But I was getting these before I added it. I was hoping to have a way for the server to tell the browser to ignore those links or proxy all the connections through my server so I can maintain a cache.